# OpenCV video - Start minimized

Tags: opencv, video, minimize

So the my code works perfect just has one hickup. I want the video run on second monitor(currently removed from code), while the primary monitor runs an application full screen. The problem is when the opencv video opens it minimizes the primary screen application. I tried the cv,namedWindow and resize with no luck. Any suggestions?

Just need primary monitor application to stay full screen while video runs on secondary. Driving me crazy.

Thanks

```
import os
from os import path
import glob
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class Watcher:
    DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH = 'PATH'

    def __init__(self):
        self.observer = Observer()

        def run(self):
        event_handler = Handler()
        self.observer.schedule(event_handler, self.DIRECTORY_TO_WATCH, recursive=True)
        self.observer.start()
        try:
            while True:

        except:
            self.observer.stop()


        self.observer.join()

class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):

    @staticmethod
    def on_any_event(event):
        if event.is_directory:
            return None

        elif event.event_type == 'created':


            os.chdir("PATH")


            newest = max(glob.glob("PATH/*.mp4"), key=os.path.getctime)



            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(newest)
            cap.set(1,1420);

            def rescale_frame(frame, percent=25):
                width = int(frame.shape[1] * percent/ 100)
                height = int(frame.shape[0] * percent/ 100)
                dim = (width, height)
                return cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation =cv2.INTER_AREA)

            while True:
                ret ,frame = cap.read()
                if type(frame) == type(None):
                    break


                frame25 = rescale_frame(frame, percent=25)
                cv2.namedWindow('frame25',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

                cv2.imshow('frame25',frame25)
                if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Watcher()
    w.run()
```

Comment: Are you sure it's actually the OpenCV code that causes the other app to minimize? Try showing some basic window using Tk, or some other GUI toolkit, and see if it behaves differently. | In general, the HighGUI module is intended as a simple prototyping tool. Whenever I need something more specific than just quickly popping up a window to show an image, I just implement my own UI.

Comment: thanks. I been looking in Tk, but I am newbie to coding and kinda throwing me for a loop. I will continue testing. I wish wnck would worth with Python 3.x seems so much easier